# Efficient sampling from nested lists

Tags: r, performance, nested, lapply

I have a ***list of lists***, containing data.frames, from which I want to ***select only a few rows***. I can achieve it in a for-loop, where I create a sequence based on the amount of rows and select only row indices according to that sequence.

But if I have deeper nested lists it doesn't work anymore. I am also sure, that there is a better way of doing that without a loop.

*What would be an efficient and generic approach to sample from nested lists, that vary in their dimensions and contain data.frames or matrices?*

```
## Dummy Data
n1=100;n2=300;n3=100
crdOrig <- list(
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n1,10,20), y = runif(n1,40,60))),
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n2,10,20), y = runif(n2,40,60))),
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n3,10,20), y = runif(n3,40,60)))
)

## Code to opimize
FiltRef <- list()
filterBy = 10
for (r in 1:length(crdOrig)) { 
  tmp <- do.call(rbind, crdOrig[[r]])
  filterInd <- seq(1,nrow(tmp), by = filterBy)
  FiltRef[[r]] <- tmp[filterInd,]
}
crdResult <- do.call(rbind, FiltRef)

# Plotting
crdOrigPl <- do.call(rbind, unlist(crdOrig, recursive = F))
plot(crdOrigPl[,1], crdOrigPl[,2], col="red", pch=20)
points(crdResult[,1], crdResult[,2], col="green", pch=20)
```

The code above works also if a list contains several data.frames *(data below)*.

```
## Dummy Data (Multiple DF)
crdOrig <- list(
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n1,10,20), y = runif(n1,40,60)),
       data.frame(x = runif(n1,10,20), y = runif(n1,40,60))),
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n2,10,20), y = runif(n2,40,60))),
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n3,10,20), y = runif(n3,40,60)))
)
```

But if a list contains multiple lists, it throws an error trying to bind the result (`FiltRef`) together.

*The result can be a data.frame with 2 columns (x,y) - like `crdResult` or a one dimensional list like `FiltRef` (from the first example)*

```
## Dummy Data (Multiple Lists)
crdOrig <- list(
  list(list(data.frame(x = runif(n1,10,20), y = runif(n1,40,60))),
       list(data.frame(x = runif(n1,10,20), y = runif(n1,40,60)))),
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n2,10,20), y = runif(n2,40,60))),
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n3,10,20), y = runif(n3,40,60)))
)
```

---

**+1 and Thank you** all for your brilliant answers! They all work and there is a lot to learn from each one of them. I will give this one to @Gwang-Jin Kim as his solution is the most flexible and extensive, although they all deserve to be checked!

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the last example.

Comment: Do you want an equal length list of lists object? So for last example, the first nested lists should be rbinded together?

Comment: I added the expected result, but yes it could also be a one dimensional list and the first nested list can be rbinded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preparation and implementation of `flatten`**

Well, there are many other answers which are in principle the same.

I meanwhile implemented for fun the flattening of nested lists.

Since I am thinking in Lisp:

Implemented first `car` and `cdr` from lisp.

```
car <- function(l) {
  if(is.list(l)) {
    if (null(l)) {
      list()
    } else {
      l[[1]]
    }
  } else {
    error("Not a list.")
  }
}

cdr <- function(l) {
  if (is.list(l)) {
    if (null(l) || length(l) == 1) {
      list()
    } else {
      l[2:length(l)]
    }
  } else {
    error("Not a list.")
  }
}
```

Some predicate functions:

```
null <- function(l) length(l) == 0   
# this is Lisp's `null` checking whether list is empty (`length(l) == 0`)
# R's `is.null()` checks for the value NULL and not `length(obj) == 0`

# upon @Martin Morgan's comment removed other predicate functions
# thank you @Martin Morgan!
# instead using `is.data.frame()` and `is.list()`, since they are
# not only already there but also safer.
```

Which are necessary to build flatten (for data frame lists)

```
flatten <- function(nested.list.construct) {
  # Implemented Lisp's flatten tail call recursively. (`..flatten()`)
  # Instead of (atom l) (is.df l).
  ..flatten <- function(l, acc.l) { 
    if (null(l)) {
      acc.l
    } else if (is.data.frame(l)) {   # originally one checks here for is.atom(l)
      acc.l[[length(acc.l) + 1]] <- l
      acc.l # kind of (list* l acc.l)
    } else {
      ..flatten(car(l), ..flatten(cdr(l), acc.l))
    }
  }
  ..flatten(nested.list.construct, list())
}

# an atom is in the widest sence a non-list object
```

After this, the actual function is defined using a sampling function.

**Defining sampling function**

```
# helper function
nrow <- function(df) dim(df)[1L]

# sampling function
sample.one.nth.of.rows <- function(df, fraction = 1/10) {
  # Randomly selects a fraction of the rows of a data frame
  nr <- nrow(df) 
  df[sample(nr, fraction * nr), , drop = FALSE]
}
```

**The actual collector function (from nested data-frame-lists)**

```
collect.df.samples <- function(df.list.construct, fraction = 1/10) {
  do.call(rbind, 
         lapply(flatten(df.list.construct), 
                function(df) sample.one.nth.of.rows(df, fraction)
               )
        )
}
# thanks for the improvement with `do.call(rbind, [list])` @Ryan!
# and the hint that `require(data.table)`
# `data.table::rbindlist([list])` would be even faster.
```

`collect.df.samples` first flattens the nested list construct of data frames `df.list.construct` to a flat list of data frames. It applies the function `sample.one.nth.of.rows` to each elements of the list (`lapply`). There by it produces a list of sampled data frames (which contain the fraction - here 1/10th of the original data frame rows). These sampled data frames are `rbind`ed across the list. The resulting data frame is returned. It consists of the sampled rows of each of the data frames.

**Testing on example**

```
## Dummy Data (Multiple Lists)
n1=100;n2=300;n3=100
crdOrig <- list(
  list(list(data.frame(x = runif(n1,10,20), y = runif(n1,40,60))),
       list(data.frame(x = runif(n1,10,20), y = runif(n1,40,60)))),
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n2,10,20), y = runif(n2,40,60))),
  list(data.frame(x = runif(n3,10,20), y = runif(n3,40,60)))
)

collect.df.samples(crdOrig, fraction = 1/10)
```

**Refactoring for later modifications**

By writing the `collect.df.samples` function to:

```
# sampler function
sample.10th.fraction <- function(df) sample.one.nth.of.rows(df, fraction = 1/10)

# refactored:
collect.df.samples <- 
  function(df.list.construct, 
           df.sampler.fun = sample.10th.fraction) {
  do.call(rbind, 
          lapply(flatten(df.list.construct), df.sampler.fun))
}
```

One can make the sampler function replace-able.
(And if not: By changing the `fraction` parameter, one can enhance or reduce amount of rows collected from each data frame.)

**The sampler function is in this definition easily exchangable**

For choosing every nth (e.g. every 10th) row in the data frame, instead of a random sampling,
you could e.g. use the sampler function:

```
df[seq(from=1, to=nrow(df), by = nth), , drop = FALSE]
```

and input it as `df.sampler.fun =` in `collect.df.samples`. Then, this function will be applied to every data frame in the nested df list object and collected to one data frame.

```
every.10th.rows <- function(df, nth = 10) {
  df[seq(from=1, to=nrow(df), by = nth), , drop = FALSE]
}

a.10th.of.all.rows <- function(df, fraction = 1/10) {
  sample.one.nth.of.rows(df, fraction)
}

collect.df.samples(crdOrig, a.10th.of.all.rows)
collect.df.samples(crdOrig, every.10th.rows)
```

Comment: Fun; FWIW R's S3 class system means that `class(x)` can return a vector of length > 1, so that `if (class(x) == "foo")` does not make sense; better to stick with `inherits()` or one of the predefined `is....()`.

Comment: Thank you @Ryan. Ah, one is always learning - `do.call(rbind, [list])` then. Didn't knew that it is faster. And great, then I should use `rbindlist()` - Thank you for this nice hint! I actually wrote before `nrow(df)` :D. Thank you for your nice feedback! I will modify then! :)

Comment: Thanks for that awesome answer!! Juts a small correction: I think a function is missing or the names are incorrect: `sample.one.nth.of.rows` is not found, I think it should be `sample.nth.of.rows`.

Comment: True, I changed them around :D - will correct. - I corrected! Welcome and thanks! It is if you have interactive R open, and then change names but the old definitions are still there ... you don't recognize certain mistakes.

Comment: I changed to `sample.one.nth.of.rows` everything.

Answer (score 4):

I would just flatten the whole darn thing and work on a clean list.

```
library(rlist)
out <- list.flatten(y)

# prepare a vector for which columns belong together
vc <- rep(1:(length(out)/2), each = 2)
vc <- split(1:length(vc), vc)

# prepare the final list
ll <- vector("list", length(unique(vc)))
for (i in 1:length(vc)) {
  ll[[i]] <- as.data.frame(out[vc[[i]]])
}

result <- lapply(ll, FUN = function(x) {
  x[sample(1:nrow(x), size = 10, replace = FALSE), ]
})

do.call(rbind, result)

           x        y
98  10.32912 52.87113
52  16.42912 46.07026
92  18.85397 46.26403
90  12.04884 57.79290
23  18.20997 40.57904
27  18.98340 52.55919
...
```

Comment: If there are not just data.frames but matrices (same dimensions) at hand `do.call(rbind, result)` doesnt work, as there are unequal columns.

Comment: @SeGa if that's the case, then you should probably get a cleaner dataset. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer in base borrowing from a custom "rapply" function mentioned here [rapply to nested list of data frames in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971073/rapply-to-nested-list-of-data-frames-in-r)

```
df_samples<-list()
i=1

f<-function(x) {
  i<<-i+1
  df_samples[[i]]<<-x[sample(rownames(x),10),]
}

recurse <- function (L, f) {
  if (inherits(L, "data.frame")) {
  f(L)  }
  else lapply(L, recurse, f)
}

recurse(crdOrig, f)

res<-do.call("rbind", df_samples)
```

Answer (score 2):

I too would flatten the list-of-lists into a standard representation (and do all analysis on the flattened representation, not just the subseting), but keep track of relevant indexing information, e.g.,

```
flatten_recursive = function(x) {
    i <- 0L
    .f = function(x, depth) {
        if (is.data.frame(x)) {
            i <<- i + 1L
            cbind(i, depth, x)
        } else {
            x = lapply(x, .f, depth + 1L)
            do.call(rbind, x)
        }
    }
    .f(x, 0L)
}
```

The internal function `.f()` visits each element of a list. If the element is a data.frame, it adds a unique identifier to index it. If it's a list, then it calls itself on each element of the list (incrementing a depth counter, in case this is useful, one could also add a 'group' counter) and then row-binds the elements. I use an internal function so that I can have a variable `i` to increment across function calls. The end result is a single data frame with a index to use for referencing the original results.

```
> tbl <- flatten_recursive(crdOrig) %>% as_tibble()
> tbl %>% group_by(i, depth) %>% summarize(n())
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   i [?]
      i depth `n()`
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3   100
2     2     3   100
3     3     2   300
4     4     2   100
> tbl %>% group_by(i) %>% slice(seq(1, n(), by = 10)) %>% summarize(n())
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      i `n()`
  <int> <int>
1     1    10
2     2    10
3     3    30
4     4    10
```

The overall pattern of `.f()` can be adjusted for additional data types, e.g., (some details omitted)

```
.f <- function(x) {
    if (is.data.frame(x)) {
        x
    } else if (is.matrix(x)) {
        x <- as.data.frame(x)
        setNames(x, c("x", "y"))
    } else {
        do.call(rbind, lapply(x, .f))
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. But is the `<<-` really necessary? It seems to work with normal `<-` too

Comment: If you look at `i` when assigned with `<-` you'll see that all indexes are `1`, rather than 1..4 -- `<-` modifies the value of `i` locally, so each call to `.f()` increments `i` from 0 to 1...

Comment: Indeed! Thank you. In my case i dont need to keep track of the data origin, but its a nice feature!

Comment: @SeGa without the `i` this method has no way of sampling each data.frame individually, so that's why it's needed.

Comment: With the real data I'm getting a `Error: C stack usage`. Why is that?

Comment: How nested is your real data?

Comment: Its a list of 6 lists, each a List of 1, but i just saw, that there are matrices aswell (like:  `..$ : num [1:200, 1:2]`), not just data.frames!

Comment: I suggested an extension to `.f()`, but you'll need to incorporate `i` and `depth`; should be easy enough and a good exercise 'for the student'!

Answer (score 2):

Consider a recursive call conditionally checking if first item is a *data.frame* or *list* class.

```
stack_process <- function(lst){
  if(class(lst[[1]]) == "data.frame") {
    tmp <- lst[[1]]
  } 

  if(class(lst[[1]]) == "list") {
    inner <- lapply(lst, stack_process)        
    tmp <- do.call(rbind, inner)
  }

  return(tmp)
}

new_crdOrig <- lapply(crdOrig, function(x) {
  df <- stack_process(x)

  filterInd <- seq(1, nrow(df), by = filterBy)
  return(df[filterInd,])
})

final_df <- do.call(rbind, new_crdOrig)
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to prefer the simpler `inner <- lapply(lst, stack_process)`, which doesn't require pre-allocation of `inner` and implicit re-allocation in the loop?

Comment: Indeed, @MartinMorgan, good point! I got caught in the weeds and couldn't see it.