# R: convert a list to a data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
mylist <- list(NULL, structure(list(Gender = structure(1L, .Label = "Female", class = "factor"), 
  ID = structure(1L, .Label = "1", class = "factor"), Class = structure(1L, .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
  Score1 = 21.6, Score2 = 39.61, Score3 = 8.85, 
  Score4 = 13.66, Score5 = 2.64999999999999, Score6 = 6.94736842105265), .Names = c("Gender", 
  "ID", "Class", "Score1", "Score2", "Score3", 
  "Score4", "Score5", "Score6"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
  ), class = "data.frame"), list(structure(list(Gender = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Female", 
  "Male"), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "2", class = "factor"), 
  Class = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
  Score1 = c(25.58, 18.31), Score2 = c(55.01, 
  36.28), Score3 = c(1.66, 2.13), Score4 = c(3.6, 
  4.24), Score5 = c(15.2727272727273, 8.57142857142858), Score6 = c(15.5833333333334, 
  8.4545454545455)), .Names = c("Gender", "ID", "Class", 
  "Score1", "Score2", "Score3", "Score4", 
  "Score5", "Score6"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), 
  structure(list(Gender = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Female", 
  "Male"), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "3", class = "factor"), 
  Class = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
  Score1 = c(27.16, 14.67), Score2 = c(58.39, 
  29.07), Score3 = c(1.66, 2.13), Score4 = c(3.6, 
  4.24), Score5 = c(16.2727272727273, 6.85714285714286), 
  Score6 = c(16.5833333333333, 6.81818181818185)), .Names = c("Gender", 
  "ID", "Class", "Score1", "Score2", 
  "Score3", "Score4", "Score5", "Score6"), row.names = c(NA,-2L), class = "data.frame")))
```

I have a list that looks like:

```
> mylist
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
  Gender ID Class Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4 Score5   Score6
1 Female  1     A   21.6  39.61   8.85  13.66   2.65 6.947368

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
  Gender ID Class Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4    Score5    Score6
1 Female  2     A  25.58  55.01   1.66   3.60 15.272727 15.583333
2   Male  2     A  18.31  36.28   2.13   4.24  8.571429  8.454545

[[3]][[2]]
  Gender ID Class Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4    Score5    Score6
1 Female  3     A  27.16  58.39   1.66   3.60 16.272727 16.583333
2   Male  3     A  14.67  29.07   2.13   4.24  6.857143  6.818182
```

Where some elements are `NULL`, and other elements can have multiple sub elements, e.g. the third element has sub elements `[[1]]` and `[[2]]`.

I would like to combine these list elements into a single data.frame that looks something like this (I'm omitting the contents of columns Score2 through Score6 for convenience):

```
  Gender ID Class Score1 Score2 ... Score6
1 Female  1     A  21.60     
2 Female  2     A  25.58    
3   Male  2     A  18.31    
4 Female  3     A  27.16    
5   Male  3     A  14.67
```

I've tried the following but got errors

```
> tab <- unlist(mylist, recursive = FALSE)
> df <- do.call("rbind", tab)
Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 1L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 1L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
...
```

Using `ldply` does not handle the last element correctly

```
> ldply(mylist, data.frame)
  Gender ID Class Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4    Score5    Score6 Gender.1 ID.1 Class.1 Score1.1 Score2.1 Score3.1 Score4.1  Score5.1  Score6.1
1 Female  1     A  21.60  39.61   8.85  13.66  2.650000  6.947368     <NA> <NA>    <NA>       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA        NA
2 Female  2     A  25.58  55.01   1.66   3.60 15.272727 15.583333   Female    3       A    27.16    58.39     1.66     3.60 16.272727 16.583333
3   Male  2     A  18.31  36.28   2.13   4.24  8.571429  8.454545     Male    3       A    14.67    29.07     2.13     4.24  6.857143  6.818182
```

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. Do you not get the data frame you want in `df`?

Comment: @camille, no I do not

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668561/efficient-sampling-from-nested-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ll <- unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) list(x) else x), recursive = FALSE)
do.call(rbind, ll)
  Gender ID Class Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4    Score5    Score6
1 Female  1     A  21.60  39.61   8.85  13.66  2.650000  6.947368
2 Female  2     A  25.58  55.01   1.66   3.60 15.272727 15.583333
3   Male  2     A  18.31  36.28   2.13   4.24  8.571429  8.454545
4 Female  3     A  27.16  58.39   1.66   3.60 16.272727 16.583333
5   Male  3     A  14.67  29.07   2.13   4.24  6.857143  6.818182
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this very simply with a couple `tidyverse` functions. `purrr::reduce` lets you apply a function across a list or vector, and `dplyr::bind_rows` is like an expanded, smarter `rbind`.

Note that, like I said in my comment, you get warnings about the fact that you're binding character vectors with factor vectors, but this is simply a *warning*, not an *error*.

```r
purrr::reduce(mylist, dplyr::bind_rows)

#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector

...

#>   Gender ID Class Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4    Score5    Score6
#> 1 Female  1     A  21.60  39.61   8.85  13.66  2.650000  6.947368
#> 2 Female  2     A  25.58  55.01   1.66   3.60 15.272727 15.583333
#> 3   Male  2     A  18.31  36.28   2.13   4.24  8.571429  8.454545
#> 4 Female  3     A  27.16  58.39   1.66   3.60 16.272727 16.583333
#> 5   Male  3     A  14.67  29.07   2.13   4.24  6.857143  6.818182
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose a generalized `unlist` function called `unlist_unless` which works like `unlist` with the following differences:

- It has a `predicate` argument used to leave some sub element untouched (formula notation is supported if `purrr` is installed)
- `...` passes arguments to `predicate`
- `keep_null` is used to keep (default) or drop `NULL` elements

Like `unlist` it features parameters `recursive` and `use.names` with same defaults.parameter set to `TRUE` by default, it also features a `keep_null` parameter that I've set to `TRUE` by default.

```
unlist_unless <- function(x, predicate = function(x) FALSE, ..., recursive = TRUE,  use.names = TRUE, keep_null = TRUE){
  if(inherits(predicate, "formula")) {
    if (requireNamespace("purrr")) predicate <- purrr::as_mapper(predicate) else
      stop("Package `purrr` needs to be installed to use formula notation")
  }

  unlist(lapply(x, function(y){
    if(predicate(y, ...) || (keep_null && is.null(y)))
      list(y)
    else if (is.list(y) && recursive)
      unlist_unless(y, predicate = predicate, ..., keep_null=keep_null, use.names = use.names)
    else y}),
    recursive = FALSE,
    use.names = use.names)
}
```

**examples1 : simplest**

```
df <- head(iris)[1:3]
dfs<- list(df[1,],
             NULL,
             list(df[2,],
                  df[3,],
                  list(df[4,]),
                  NULL))

unlist_unless(dfs, is.data.frame)
# [[1]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 2          4.9           3          1.4
# 
# [[4]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3
# 
# [[5]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5
# 
# [[6]]
# NULL
```

**examples2 : keep_null = FALSE**

```
unlist_unless(dfs, is.data.frame, keep_null = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4
# 
# [[2]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 2          4.9           3          1.4
# 
# [[3]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3
# 
# [[4]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5

unlist_unless(dfs, is.data.frame, recursive = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 2          4.9           3          1.4
# 
# [[4]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3
# 
# [[5]]
# [[5]][[1]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5
# 
# 
# [[6]]
# NULL
```

Then it's straightforward to call `bind_rows(dfs_new)` or `do.call(rbind, dfs_new)` on the result.

```
do.call(rbind,unlist_unless(dfs, is.data.frame))

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5


# or
library(dplyr)
unlist_unless(dfs, is.data.frame) %>% bind_rows
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5
```